# Issue with Playwright typescript getting "Error: locator.click: Browser has been closed" on last locator in array

Tags: typescript, playwright, playwright-typescript

I seem to be having an issue in Playwright when looping through an array of locators. Playwright seems to give an error on the last item in the array. Error: locator.click: Browser has been closed on last item.

I written this against a public playground site so you can run this on your side as well.

```
test('should test menu items', async ({page}) => {
    await page.goto(`https://ecommerce-playground.lambdatest.io/index.php?common/home`);
    //line below returns the locators
    let menuItems = await page.locator("#entry_217841 nav div ul li").all();
    //just wanted to confirm menuItems
    //console.log(menuItems);
    for (let i=0;i <= (menuItems.length -1); i++ ){
        //click Shop by Category to activate the slide out menu
        await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Shop by Category' }).click();
        //click on the item in the slide out menu
        await menuItems[i].click();
        //console.log(await menuItems2[i].innerText());
    }
});
```

I tried changing the for loop by changing the length-10 and still getting error. I was expecting it to finish without a problem. But getting the same issue.
for (let i=0;i <= (menuItems.length -10); i++ ){

Comment: Good catch. I was going to fast... I added that missing await and still having the same issue.

Comment: There seems to be some flakiness on using trusted events on a menu that's opening and closing with an animation. The Shop by Category button also seems unreliable when used on the actual site. I can write an answer using untrusted clicks, but it depends on your goals here, which aren't yet clear--what are you actually trying to accomplish here? Is there specific data you want to extract from each page? You can get menu text without clicking anything.

Comment: You can access this public demo page here: ecommerce-playground.lambdatest.io/index.php?common/home 

I am just trying to figure out why this logic does not work. It is cleaner code and would like to use it if I can solve the issue. 

Basically fetching a list of locators and storing into an array then looping through the array using the click() seems to have issues on the last item in the array.

Comment: Thanks, I understand all that, but what's your high-level goal in doing all of this? It's hard to write an answer that just solves your immediate problem without knowing what you're trying to achieve in the first place. Most of the clicking here seems pointless.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but the trusted clicks Playwright uses on ElementHandles are flaky because they require visibility. The page itself also seems to have some glitchiness when I interact with it as a human user. The Shop By Category button seems to fail, in particular.

One approach to avoid flakiness is to use untrusted clicks:

```js
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.30.0

test("should test menu items", async ({page}) => {
  await page.goto("<Your URL>");
  const menuItems = await page
    .locator("#entry_217841 nav li")
    .all();
  const actual = [];

  for (const item of menuItems) {
    await page
      .getByRole("button", {name: "Shop by Category"})
      .evaluate(e => e.click());
    await item.evaluate(e => e.click());
    actual.push(await item.innerText());
  }

  const expected = [
    "Components",
    "Cameras",
    "Phone, Tablets & Ipod",
    "Software",
    "MP3 Players",
    "Laptops & Notebooks",
    "Desktops and Monitors",
    "Printers & Scanners",
    "Mice and Trackballs",
    "Fashion and Accessories",
    "Beauty and Saloon",
    "Autoparts and Accessories",
    "Washing machine",
    "Gaming consoles",
    "Air conditioner",
    "Web Cameras",
  ];
  expect(actual).toStrictEqual(expected);
});
```

Now, all of the clicks here aren't actually doing anything pertinent to the data you're extracting, so you can simply remove them.

Furthermore, this test doesn't use web assertions, so it's not best practice and is just given to illustrate the point.

If your goal is to assert that the menu items have certain text, a better approach is:

```js
test("should test menu items", async ({page}) => {
  await page.goto("<Your URL>");
  const expected = [
    "Components",
    "Cameras",
    "Phone, Tablets & Ipod",
    "Software",
    "MP3 Players",
    "Laptops & Notebooks",
    "Desktops and Monitors",
    "Printers & Scanners",
    "Mice and Trackballs",
    "Fashion and Accessories",
    "Beauty and Saloon",
    "Autoparts and Accessories",
    "Washing machine",
    "Gaming consoles",
    "Air conditioner",
    "Web Cameras",
  ];
  const menuItems = page.locator("#entry_217841 nav li");
  await expect(menuItems).toHaveText(expected);
});
```

This is a best practice, reliable, web-first assertion, in addition to being far simpler to write.

But if this isn't what you want to do, please provide details so I can write an answer that helps achieve whatever your actual goal is. Perhaps you want to extract some text from each page? Are you trying to test the buttons, or the navigations? If you're trying to test the buttons, using trusted events is ideal since it better replicates the user experience.

Comment: You're right, that page is flakey. I ran my logic on a different site and is working as expected. 
This wasn't really a real test, rather just checking to see how the page.locator().all() could be used then iterated through.
Thanks for your help.